# Convert time mm:ss from character to numeric

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

My Time data is part of a bigger dataframe (`DF`):

| Time: |
| --- |
| 45:31 |
| 46:26 |
| 36:04 |
| 56:44 |
| 103:02 |

I run this code to convert it from character to numeric:

```r
DF <- mutate(DF,Time = as.POSIXlt(Time,format="%M:%S"))
```

Then I use `dplyr` to summarise to get the mean but my Time values return NA

Answer (score 0):

I would use `ms()` from `lubridate`:

```r
DF <- data.frame(Time = c("45:31", "46:26", "36:04", "56:44", "103:02"))

DF <- dplyr::mutate(DF,
                    Time = lubridate::ms(Time),
                    Time_min = as.numeric(Time)/60)

summary(DF$Time)
#>                    Min.                 1st Qu.                  Median 
#>                "36M 4S"               "45M 31S"               "46M 26S" 
#>                    Mean                 3rd Qu.                    Max. 
#> "57M 33.4000000000001S"               "56M 44S"             "1H 43M 2S"

summary(DF$Time_min)
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>   36.07   45.52   46.43   57.56   56.73  103.03
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Andrea - thank you so much, it worked - it is just that my data is in a dataframe format and I have numerous columns that need to be changed from character to numeric

Comment: DF in my example is also a dataframe. To convert multiple columns you can use `mutate(across(..., ...))` - see here https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html.